# Spring Boot EntityManagerFactory not defined and @ManyToOne Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am working on restfull web services with Spring boot and JPA but I have some problems like that

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project SpringRest: An exception occurred while
>   running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with
>   name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a
>   @ManyToOne property: com.maven.nurcanyilmaz.models.Employee.department

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For JSP compilation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id",nullable=false,unique=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Description",nullable=false)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Department() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

   @Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id",nullable=false,unique=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="Name",nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Surname",nullable=false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name="Salary",nullable=false)
    private double salary;

    @Column(name="Department" , nullable=false)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id",referencedColumnName="Id")
    private Department department;

    public Employee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

repositories

```
import com.maven.nurcanyilmaz.models.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

    Employee findByName(String name);

}


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.maven.nurcanyilmaz.models.Department;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DepartmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Department, Long> {

    Department findByName(String name);
}
```

application.properties

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
server.port=8088

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EmployeeDb
spring.datasource.username =root
spring.datasource.password =test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the exception? `@Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property` is pretty clear on what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Employee Entity for private department department, You are using @column and @joinColumn  together which seems to be the problem. Looking at your entities you are supposed to use @JoinColumn there but not @Column.

Comment: thank you but I have still entitymanagerfactory exception. By the way @joinColumn has two work. Giving name and mapping. so I can't use them together this is right?

Comment: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController' defined in file [/home/nurcan/workspace/SpringRest/target/classes/com/maven/controllers/DepartmentController.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified field type [interface com.maven.nurcanyilmaz.repositories.DepartmentRepository] is incompatible with resource type [javax.persistence.EntityManager]

Comment: You shouldn't use them together. I just replaced @ Column with @ JoinColumn and the error disappeared. Thank you @Madhu Reddy.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate does not allow to use `@Column` annotation along with `@ManyToOne`.

You can use `@JoinColumn` if you want to specify the column name

Answer (score 3):

As the error description suggests you should not have `@Column` annotation on your `@ManyToOne` property. `@JoinColumn` is all your need.

Please refer to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne